# Get the database name from a PyMongo object

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am currently working on a flask project that uses several blueprints and mongo for data storage. I have created multiple PyMongo instances in order to reach different databases:

In app.py which is the core file of the project I have defined the instances:

```
# The PyMongo instance 'mongo_app' takes its uri from the project's config.
mongo_app.init_app(app)

# The second PyMongo instance is initialized with the needed uri.
mongo_project.init_app(app, uri="mongodb://mongodb:27017/rick_and_morty")
```

In a blueprint of the project I need the name of the database with which the PyMongo object 'mongo_project' has been initialized, namely 'rick_and_morty'.

My question is, how can I suck this information out of the PyMongo object? Something like the following I am trying to achieve:

```
database_name = mongo_project.db_name #rick_and_morty
```

Comment: What does `init_app` do when passing `app` and `uri` as argument?

Comment: I have not looked deeper into it, but only can refer to the API of flask-pymongo: (https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
Technically it binds your mongo reference to the application and makes the database accessible all over your project by for example accessing a collection: mongo_instance.db.collection_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach them to the Flask app and access with current_app

```
# app.py
from collections import namedtuple
from flask import Flask
from my_blueprint import app_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.mongo_project = namedtuple("whatever", ["db_name"])(db_name="db_name_1")
app.register_blueprint(app_blueprint)

# my_blueprint.py
from flask import Blueprint, current_app

app_blueprint = Blueprint('app_blueprint', __name__)

@app_blueprint.route("/blueprint_route")
def foobar():
    database_name = current_app.mongo_project.db_name
    return database_name
```

Comment: That is a really simple and nice solution to the problem. I have not been aware of saving the application context so easily! Thanks a lot @Fian!

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use *uri_parser* from pymongo: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/uri_parser.html

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jun  9 2017, 18:24:27) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo
>>> parsed=pymongo.uri_parser.parse_uri('mongodb://mongodb:27017/rick_and_morty')
>>> print parsed['database']
rick_and_morty
```

Comment: That is also a valid solution and good to know about. Thank you @thev0id!